# No enum constant com.android.manifmerger.NodeOperationType.MERGE-ONLY-ATTRIBUTES

Tags: android, gradle

this is my code in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
      android:name=".ui.FlashActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      tools:node="merge-only-attributes">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But when i build the project,a problem occurs:

---

**What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDevelopDebugManifest'.
No enum constant com.android.manifmerger.NodeOperationType.MERGE-ONLY-ATTRIBUTES**

anyone can help me? 3ks

Answer (score 6):

Try using `"mergeOnlyAttributes"` instead of `"merge-only-attributes"` ... their logic around string-vs-enum seems to have gotten messed up.

The enum value is definitely still there: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/build-system/manifest-merger/src/main/java/com/android/manifmerger/NodeOperationType.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F#45

Answer (score 0):

This "merge-only-attributes" thing seems gone. I can not make it work, either. But maybe you can try using the 'tools:node="remove"' in the elements you want to remove from a lower priority AndroidManifest.xml if they are known. like

```
<activity
  android:name=".ui.FlashActivity"
  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="some.action.to.remove"
                tools:node="remove"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Or even remove the whole intent-filter:

```
<activity
  android:name=".ui.FlashActivity"
  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    <intent-filter tools:node="removeAll"/>
</activity>
```